# What weapon does Clyde use to kill his cell mate?

Tags: plot-explanation, law-abiding-citizen

I was watching the movie [*Law Abiding Citizen*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/). I can't quite figure out what weapon *Clyde* uses to kill his cell mate. It didn't look like a knife. And whatever it was, where did he get that from in a cell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clyde Shelton bargains with Nick Rice to give the location of Bill Reynolds, (Darby's attorney) in return for a 20 ounce Porterhouse steak (medium rare with all the trimmings) from Del Frisco's to be delivered at precisely 1 p.m., along with his iPod. Warden Inger demands multiple delays, resulting in the food arriving at Shelton's cell eight minutes late. Rice and Detective Dunnigan find Reynolds buried alive and only minutes dead, with Inger's delay causing him to suffocate, his oxygen tank having been set to shut down at 1:15. Dunnigan explains that because Shelton received his lunch at 1:08, they were 7 minutes late instead of getting to Reynolds in time to save him.

Meanwhile Shelton shares the steak dinner with his cellmate. Shelton palms the steak's T-bone and while distracting his cellmate with the iPod, murders him by using the T-bone as a push-knife. It gets messy and the Duxiana bed gets wrecked.

Edit to add information: The 'T-bone', including 'Porterhouse', is cut from the Short loin (top of the back). To cut a T-bone from butchered cattle, a lumbar vertebra is sawn in half through the vertebral column. The downward prong of the 'T' is a transverse process of the vertebra, and the flesh surrounding it is the spinal muscles. The small semicircle at the top of the 'T' is half of the vertebral foramen. This is a very strong bone and would make a very effective push-knife.

Comment: are you sure it was T bone? I agree the way he was holding it indicates it was T bone though. But it even fairly possible to kill someone with a T-bone? You have to hit real hard to pierce someone will it not break?

Comment: @Arbaaz - it was the T-bone

Comment: @Arbaaz, have you ever seen a compound fracture? A sharp bone will easily pierce flesh.

Comment: It was a T-Bone. Have you ever had a T-Bone steak? You ain't breaking that thing with your bare hands unless you're a beast. Morgan is correct in his answer.

Comment: I thought it was the _spork_, Clyde uses.

Comment: @DustinDavis I have never had a T Bone steak. Thanks All of you.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher - He used the 'spork' to stab the asparagus.

Comment: @Arbaaz The bone is nicely seen on the photo [here](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/rmarmion/rmarmion1204/rmarmion120400438/13150397-single-grilled-t-bone-steak-on-a-white-background.jpg).